# web application cannot see tables in new postgresql schema

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I moved some tables in my postgresql (8.2) database to a new schema.
at first, my "user" could not see the tables in the new schema, but I used set search_path to tell it to look in this new schema

I access these tables with a simple web application that uses hibernate.  At first, my web application, which uses the "user" user, could not see the tables either, even after I set the search_path.  I eventually set the default-schema in the hibernate config file and it worked, but I understand from what I've read that I should not have to set this property?  I have a few JDBC queries in this app that still can't see the tables in the new schema.

I've browsed through the postgresql docs and can't find the cause of my problems.  Is there something simple I'm missing?

Comment: How did you "change the search path"? Did you use `ALTER USER` or set search_path? Did you commit the `ALTER USER`?

Comment: I used the command "SET search_path TO mystuff, myotherstuff " without ALTER USER ....   I don't have permissions to ALTER USER

Comment: I don't think SET search_path is persisted. It is only valid for the current session. You need to use ALTER USER to make that change permanently. I think you can change "yourself" though.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name is right on. I just went through this not long ago.  It only persists for that session.

Comment: sure enough.  I did change "myself" and now everything works.  Quick, post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SET search_path` is not persisted. It is only valid for the current session.

You need to use `ALTER USER` to make that change permanently, but you don't need special privileges to change the user you are logged in with (i.e. "yourself")